# Why does adding a Header view to a MvxListView derivative disrupt the binding process?

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm currently using MvvmCross for new app projects, and I'm trying to display a header view with a MvxListView. Reading discussions such as [this](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/331) has led me to understand that a headerview cannot be added after the adapter has been set, so the constructor must be overridden so that the header is added before the MvxAdapter is set. This has led me to implement the following class:

```
public class HeaderListView : MvxListView
{
    public FrameLayout HeaderFrame { get; set; }

    public HeaderListView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs)
        : this(context, attrs, new MvxAdapter(context))
    {
    }

    public HeaderListView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, IMvxAdapter adapter) 
        : base(context, attrs, null)
    {
        InitializeHeader(context);
        // Note: Any calling derived class passing a null adapter is responsible for setting
        // it's own itemTemplateId
        if (adapter == null)
            return;

        var itemTemplateId = MvxAttributeHelpers.ReadListItemTemplateId(context, attrs);
        adapter.ItemTemplateId = itemTemplateId;
        Adapter = adapter;
    }

    private void InitializeHeader(Context context)
    {
        HeaderFrame = new FrameLayout(context);
        AddHeaderView(HeaderFrame);
    }
}
```

Pay particular attention to the InitializeHeader call in the second constructor. When I comment this line out, the test application starts up fine and this HeaderListView behaves indistinguishably from a standard MvxListView. However, uncomment that line and you are greeted with a blank ListView and a number of binding errors:

```
MvxBind:Error: 10.86 Problem seen during binding execution for binding ItemsSource for Names - problem TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
02-02 23:33:01.948 I/mono-stdout( 2323): MvxBind:Error: 10.86 Problem seen during binding execution for binding ItemsSource for Names - problem TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
      at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.Target.MvxPropertyInfoTargetBinding.SetValueImpl (System.Object target, System.Object value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
02-02 23:33:01.948 I/mono-stdout( 2323):      at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
02-02 23:33:01.948 I/mono-stdout( 2323):   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
02-02 23:33:01.958 I/mono-stdout( 2323):   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.Target.MvxPropertyInfoTargetBinding.SetValueImpl (System.Object target, System.Object value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.Target.MvxConvertingTargetBinding.SetValue (System.Object value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.MvxFullBinding.UpdateTargetFromSource (System.Object value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
InnerException was NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
      at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Views.MvxListView.set_ItemsSource (IEnumerable value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
02-02 23:33:01.958 I/mono-stdout( 2323):   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.Target.MvxConvertingTargetBinding.SetValue (System.Object value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
02-02 23:33:01.968 I/mono-stdout( 2323):   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.MvxFullBinding.UpdateTargetFromSource (System.Object value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
02-02 23:33:01.968 I/mono-stdout( 2323): InnerException was NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
02-02 23:33:01.968 I/mono-stdout( 2323):      at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Views.MvxListView.set_ItemsSource (IEnumerable value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
02-02 23:33:01.968 I/mono-stdout( 2323):   at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I can't make any sense at all of this error, because the only difference that causes its appearance is that I assign a header view before assigning the adapter, but that has nothing whatsoever to do with the adapter. What is the source of this error, and how can I work around it?

The full source of my sample project demonstrating this problem is available [on github](https://github.com/pdusen/mvvmcross-header).

Answer (score 3):

The reason has to do with the hacky way that headers and footers were added to ListView. When you add a header or footer to a ListView, when you set the adapter for the list view, it wraps your adapter in a HeaderViewListAdapter that returns the headers and footers as though they were just rows before and after the actual rows your adapter returns.

The reason this fails with MvxListView is its Adpater property which looks like this:

```
    public new IMvxAdapter Adapter
    {
        get { return base.Adapter as IMvxAdapter; }
        set
        {
            // Code to copy ItemsSource and template ID

            base.Adapter = value;
        }
    }
```

It does not store the IMvxAdapter instance you give it. It just sets it in the base.Adapter and expects when it gets base.Adapter later it will be the same value it set earlier. But that is not true when headers and footers are added to the list. The class you get back from base.Adapter will be a HeaderViewListAdapter that wraps the instance of IMvxAdapter that was set earlier.

There is no good way to work around this as a user of MvxList (other than copy and change MvxList). The fix for Stuart would be to not rely on base.Adapter for the getter, but instead store the value into a field in the setter and return that from the getter.

Answer (score 3):

By adding ItemsSource in the .axml file causes the List to set an Adapter and you can not add a header/footer to a listview when an Adapter is set.

I had a similar issue and ended using 
[MvxListWithHeader](https://github.com/jquintus/spikes/tree/master/XamarinSpikes/MvxListWithHeader) - It allows you to add a header and footer to a MvxListView.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any obvious reason behind the error.

It doesn't look like the "binding process" is being disrupted from your trace. Instead it looks like the Adapter is somehow being stuck at `null`.

One suggestion to help debug further - if you add a new ItemsSource to your custom list view, then this will be used for binding - and will give you a place to put a breakpoint so that you can investigate the state of the ListView control during the `set_ItemsSource`  null reference problem.

```
    [MvxSetToNullAfterBinding]
    public new IEnumerable ItemsSource
    {
        get { return Adapter.ItemsSource; }
        set { 
            // here is where null is being reported
            // add a breakpoint and examine Adapter and ((ListView)this).Adapter in the watch window
            Adapter.ItemsSource = value; 
        }
    }
```

Beyond this, you could try copying all the MvxListView code into your view to see if that helps identify the issue.

Comment: I'm also experiencing this kind of behavior (on version 4.0 of mvvmcross).

I know this is an old post, but did something came up in the mean time ?

I also have a very simple viewmodel with a List property named "Items".

I bind the ItemsSource to Items in my .axml file. If in my fragment I add a header view to the binded ListView, the assignment of the "Items" property fails to a NullReferenceException. If I remove the code from my fragment, it works like a charm.